# Open music player on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-intent

This following code works on any android device (api >= 8) but not on Samsung Galaxy S3 (music player not found).

```
try {
    String name;
    try {
        name = (String) MediaStore.class.getDeclaredField("INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER").get(null);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        name = (String) Intent.class.getDeclaredField("CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC").get(null);
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(name));
} catch(Exception e) {
    // music player not found
}
```

Samsung constructor layer is something to it? Does anyone have a solution to open the media player on a Galaxy S3?

As an update, I have changed my mistake but I still no get mediaplayer on Galaxy S3:

```
try {
    try {
        // 8 <= API < 15
        String action = (String) MediaStore.class.getDeclaredField("INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER").get(null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // 15 <= API
        String category = (String) Intent.class.getDeclaredField("CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC").get(null);
        Method method = Intent.class.getMethod("makeMainSelectorActivity", String.class, String.class);
        Intent intent = (Intent) method.invoke(null, Intent.ACTION_MAIN, category);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
catch(Exception e) {
    // music player not found
}
```

Comment: Did you try running this on GS3 - JB? If it still happens let me know.

Comment: No, I tested it on Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0.3 (API level 15): no problem music player found, and Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4 (API level 15): music player not found. Note: neither of two phones have a custom ROM

Comment: I will report this to the concerned group but I'm not sure if this will be fixed in JB or not. (Because the updates have already started rolling out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem with the following steps:

- I installed "Package Name" application from Android Market
- I found music player's package named "com.sec.android.app.music"
- I created an Intent with "getLaunchIntentForPackage" method from PackageManager
- I start activity with this Intent, music player is found

This generated Intent converted to String returns :

```
Intent {
    act=android.intent.action.MAIN
    cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
    flg=0x10000000
    pkg=com.sec.android.app.music
    cmp=com.sec.android.app.music/.MusicActionTabActivity
}
```

I don't understand why "CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC" doesn't works only on GS3...

The code to launch music player:

```
try {
    String pkgname = "com.sec.android.app.music";
    PackageManager pkgmanager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pkgmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // music player not found
}
```

Comment: I think Samsung doesn't register his music player replacer with CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC category on GS3. When I test this code, I have no result: startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC), "Choose music player"));

Answer (score 1):

CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC is a category. opening an intent directly on this won't work.

According to the documentation :

> public static final String CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC
>
> Since: API Level 15
>   Used with ACTION_MAIN to launch the music application. The activity should be able to play, browse, or manipulate music files stored on the device.
>
> NOTE: This should not be used as the primary key of an Intent, since it will not result in the app launching with the correct action and category. Instead, use this with makeMainSelectorActivity(String, String) to generate a main Intent with this category in the selector

you need to open it using action MAIN and setting the category as CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(mpath + "/" + filename)), "audio/"+extension);
 try {
   startActivity(intent);
 } catch ( Exception e ) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
 try {
       startActivity(intent);
     } catch ( Exception e ) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: never call `startActivity()` for external activities without `try/catch` or your app will crash if there's none

Comment: I would like open mediaplayer without any filename to input, let user choose his playlist

Comment: Thank you ankitmakwana for your edit but like you can see in my code, MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER doesn't works. does it in your code on Galaxy S3?