# using intent for launching music player

Tags: java, android, android-intent

im trying to launch the music player but it just doesn't work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
```

The app crashes,it suppose to be simple but i have no idea why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It might be raised ActivityNotFoundException. right?

That intent is deprecated in API Level 15 (ICS MR1).

And I guess your phone manufacturer missed that intent in music app.

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC instead.

Comment: it doesn't work either, i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532207/open-music-player-on-galaxy-s3 and there's a code there that actually works but it only launches the basic music app, it doesn't let me choose which one i want to launch

Comment: If there are multiple application that handle that intent, ActivityManagerService will launch ChooserActivity which can choose.
But there is only one application can handle, ActivityManagerService will launch apps directly.