# Implicit intents not showing all available options

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using Implicit `Intents` to open Music player from my application but it is not showing default music player which Android provides
Here default MIUI music player option is missing

This is how i am calling my `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Same thing happens with Gallery

```
Intent gallery = new Intent();
gallery.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
gallery.setType("image/*");
gallery.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(gallery);
```

This code automatically opens Google Photo app instead of default Gallery Application
Is there any extra line that i need to add while calling my intent??

> Note:- I cant open app using PackageName as I want user to choose the
>   app which he wants to open 
> I also cant pass the `uri` as I don't want
>   to open any photo or music file by default

Comment: Try using `Intent.CreateChooser` Ex: `startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);`

Comment: Not working @VipulAsri tried just now, this also directly opened Google Photos app

Comment: I do not have `MIUi` to test on. try to implement [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent) . If this is a Device dependent issue Try to dig in a bit. I can not say much about custom OS because they have lots of differences when it comes to implicit intent.

Comment: I think i am missing something while calling intent because intent from other application shows defult apps as well

Comment: I have tested on HTC and it worked . I can not make any assumption for `MIUI` right now . Will get back to if i find the solution .

Comment: sure one more thing i cant pass uri as i simply want to open Music player or The gallery

Comment: Have a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532207/open-music-player-on-galaxy-s3?rq=1

Comment: @SanthoshJoseph I cant do that as i want user to choose from the following chooser i cant force him to open music player from PackageName